# Why do we need to redefine widow closing methods in Java?

Tags: java

I need to know that why we need to redefine window closing methods.

I tried looking up the web to find any answer but couldn't find any answer.

// no code

any answer?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. I've written several GUI programs using java but I never felt the need to redefine window closing methods. Why do you think this is necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this used to be a thing with AWT.

IIRC the classes provided a default method that did nothing, and it was up to you to overload it - in order to do things like send any appropriate notifications that your app was closing, save any unsaved data, release any resources you'd squirreled away and so on and so forth.

---

From that point of view it makes sense.  The framework doesn't know what you want to do on closing, so it provides a place for your code to go.

Since this (or any 'why?' question) is a tad philosophical, allow me to lean into that with a brief diversion which illustrates a different approach to the same problem:

On the Mac they had a similar but different concept with 'delegates'.  E.g. rather than subclassing Window, I would hand the Window a 'Window-Lifecycle-Delegate-iser' and then the api would invoke the appropriate methods on my delegate when and if they happened.

Partly that works well for the Mac because Objective-C was a bit more Smalltalk-y than Java.  In particular you could send a message (read as: invoke a method) to an object and if the object didn't speak that message (read as: there was no corresponding method on the object), then in Objective-C it just goes nowhere, whereas in Java it dies screaming.

So in Java you have to implement every method on the Interface, whereas for Objective-C you only do the ones you actually care about.  So you can then make a big-ass API with 50-100 calls it might make to the delegate, and you won't overwhelm the developer because they can ignore 95-99% of them.

---

Here's some code from the Java SE tutorial:

```
public class HelloWorldSwing {
/**
 * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
 * this method should be invoked from the
 * event-dispatching thread.
 */
  private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

So here we see we have this method which creates a JFrame (a fancy window) and then immediately specifies how it wants the behaviour of the app to go when the user tries to exit.  In this case they're just picking a bulk standard option.

EXIT_ON_CLOSE isn't the only option, you might find it interesting to look at them.

This is important because later on:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
```

We see that the app is running inside its own thread.

So behind the scenes the computer has some kind of infinite loop which is keeping the UI alive.  And that part of it needs to know that it's okay to break out of that loop and let the thread die.

(invokeLater, Runnable and run are all clues that we're dealing with threading here :D )